# Add conditional where condition to hook_views_query_alter()

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I was stucked making a few tweaks to a view trying to do the following. 
In mysql exists the possibility to use WHERE IF to evaluate some variable/operation to apply differents conditions depending on the result/value, like a common IF/ELSE block, is there any way to do it with add_where() or any other similar method?
I need to apply a WHERE condition to the query when the value of a variable called $scope is G and a different when its L, there's any way to achieve that?

What I need to do is to do this query on Drupal 7 Views hooks

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 AS t1 JOIN tbl2 AS t2 ON t2.entity_id = t1.nid JOIN tbl3 AS t3 ON t3.entity_id = t1.uid  WHERE t1.status = 1 AND t1.type = "article" AND IF(t2.field_alcance_nodo_value = '{char}', t3.field_pais_usuario_value = '{string}', t3.field_pais_usuario_value LIKE '%') ORDER BY t1.changed DESC;
```

but I'm stucked on the IF part...
I'm using the hook_views_query_alter() but I don't know if it's enough.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `switch-case` or `if-else` in `mymodule_views_query_alter`.

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  //Get your variable $scope here
  switch($scope) {
    case 'G':
      $query->add_where_expression(0, "$variable = :placeholder", array(':placeholder' => 'value');      
      break;
    case 'L':
      $query->add_where_expression(0, "$another_variable = :another_placeholder", array(':another_placeholder' => 'another_value');      
      break;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.